# How to tell the integrity of a recovered file, specifically if pixel data of recovered image is corrupted

Tags: hard-disk, ext4, data-recovery, images

I delete a file from disk, then do some write operations on the same disk, and then run a recovery program to recover the said file.

Is there any way to check the integrity of the file?

Let the recovered file be an bitmap image. In my understanding since the data blocks that store the image pixel data may be overwritten, some pixels of an image may have wrong information. If the file header data is corrupted the file simply won't open.

But how can you tell if the pixel data is corrupted, if not visually inspecting each pixel individually? Same idea for checking integrity of text or video files.

Comment: Heuristically, maybe. If the file is expected to have some particular format, internal segments with headers or so, some random garbage might not fit the bill. Text files also don't usually have all byte values, e.g. the ones corresponding to NUL and control codes are quite rare. Maybe image compression artifacts could also be detected even if the file was otherwise decodable.

Comment: Load the file into whichever bitmap editor you use. Does it fail to load? Does it look right? Can you use it the same way you could before "loss and recovery"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some file systems have metadata blocks with checksums. With a lot of luck, these might still be intact, but typically, the metadata would be gone, so all you have is the intrinsic ability of the file itself to detect error.

First things first: images are relatively large files, and deleted files without remaining metadata that were fragmented basically can only through luck / try and error be rearranged in the same order again. Luckily, often when you write images, that happens in a very unfragmented manner.

But if it happens in an unfragmented manner, than only a fragmented write to the middle of the existing image data would lead to a corruption as you describe, and it would not be "a few pixels", it'd be e.g. a 4 kB block of image data. Very rarely you store uncompressed imagery, so honestly, your "failure mode" is not that realistic.

Now, we do see corrupted files, especially on SD cards from cameras and such. But these are different failure modes, and really only affect smaller parts of an image, or cut it short.

> But how can you tell if the pixel data is corrupted, if not visually inspecting each pixel individually?

Teach an algorithm to do your visual inspection for you. Or use file formats with checksums. I bet a few of the medical image formats would make sense.

Also, again, there's not gonna be corrupted individual pixels, 4 kB blocks will just be completely randomly broken.

But nobody designs file formats to be "after-deletion recoverable"; that's nonsense, if you need that, you actually need to stop deleting things you don't have a backup of – and snapshots of modern file systems and storage subsystems make having a backup trivial and not very space intense.

> Same idea for checking integrity of text or video files.

As said, if the only thing that can assess the content of a piece of data is a human, then that's it. For typical fotographic content, e.g. cognitive vision through deep/convolutional neural networks might be an appropriate way to detect 4 kB of "unsuitable" data being decoded e.g. by a JPEG decoder.

Comment: Very informative answer! But if the data block of 4kb points to new data, and it does not fill the whole block, ex say it's a text file with few characters, will the old pixel data be cleared from the block? I care specifically for ext4 file format.

Comment: I don't think any modern storage devices will do writes smaller than their physical block size. So, yes, a 10 B text file (aside from the fact that many file systems will just put it in the same block together with its metadata) will wipe the whole 4 kB.

Comment: Good to know thanks!

Comment: You're more than welcome! If you're looking for interesting failure modes, look into how flash memory fails on a physical basis (namely, actually bitwise, and actually only in one direction, typically 1->0), and how that is mitigated (using Error-Correcting Codes, and deinterleaving). You'll see that the cheaper the flash, the less error correction it can do (because that needs extra storage space that the operating system never sees, thanks to the flash abstraction layer built into the SSD or SD card) , and that some kind of small-scope errors become likelier.